# convert a history table to temporal table

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

i have a history table that i'd like to convert to a sql server temporal history table.  Every day, i take a snapshot of the data and add it to the table, regardless of changes.  I'm able to use this to get a point in time for each day of the year.  and since i have 3 years of data, i can get a 3 year comparison of the day for each year.  Anyway, these tables are getting rather large.  We'd like to start using temporal tables.  I've been trying to figure out if i can convert these history tables to a temporal history table with the proper from and to dates based on the date added in the current table.
The examples i've found don't seem to allow for this.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: can you provide example data? e.g for the scenario that you have a table with two columns. Day 1 you have two rows with IDs 1 and 2. Day 2 you add a row with ID 3 and update Row2. Day 3 you delete row 1 and update Row2 again. What does your current snapshot table look like at the end?